# Script to insert text at the beginning of a fields data in filemaker

Tags: insert, filemaker

I'm setting up a field to enter call follow notes.  How can I have a script enter new data at the beginning of a fields data (without deleting the existing content in the field)

Comment: New data from where?

Answer (score 1):

To add data to a field while retaining its existing content you can use the set field step on said field and include the field in the calculation:

```
Set Field [mytable::myfield ; mytable::myfield & " my new content"  ]
```

If you include more detail in your question you may get a more elaborate answer.

Comment: For new data at the beginning, the answer would be the other way around: "My new content " & mytable::myfield